# How can I add my mom to my address

Tags: united-kingdom

So, my mom moved from Italy to the Uk to be with me and open a new business. I need to add her to my address in order to start all the paperwork (NIN, business documents, and so on). How can I add her to my current address? Who do I need to contact for that? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean? As long as she is living with you, she just gives your address whenever anyone asks.

Answer (score 3):

In UK there is nothing like the Italian "anagrafe". The only way to prove your address is with utility bill or bank statements.
In case she doesn't have any bank account/contract in her name, you can write a letter stating that she lives with you.

This is not accepted everywhere and you usually need an "official" document but you can use it to request the NIN (that's what my wife did). Check [this website](https://www.gov.uk/apply-national-insurance-number) for how to apply for NIN. They will send you a letter (which you can use as proof of address in some cases) and invite your mother for an appointment.
In other cases you can use normal correspondence showing her name and address.

Requesting a driving licence doesn't require proof of address and you will get a document with her address on. You need to get the relevant form from the post office: she cannot apply on-line since she doesn't have a British passport.

You can then use the provisional driving licence to open a bank account in her name.
The use the bank account statement (and the driving licence) as proof of address.